# Connect 5 game implementation using Java and Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am working on a Connect 5 game. There is an example of such a game [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/five-in-a-line.html). Even though it is not the best solution I will be using Java and [Processing](https://processing.org/) for GUI. I want to create a 2-D array where each element is either zero, one, or two. Initially, every element is zero, and then I will update values to be 1 or 2 depending on who's move it was. I am planning to break it up into several functions:

```
boolean gameEnd(int move){
    // returns true is player 1 or player 2 just won
    // else return false
}

void makeMove(int column, int player){
    // checks the first available square in the columns and updates the value with 1 or 2
}

void drawMap(int [][] map){
    // draws a map using processing depending on the current state of map
}

int getMove(){
    // Depending on the coordinate of the click calculate the column where the move was made
}

void setup(){
    // initialize array
    // call draw function
}
```

I am a little bit skeptical about this idea and feel that it could be implemented in a better way. Also, I am not sure of the best way to implement the drawMap function. I would appreciate any help, directions, and guides on how to implement the game using Java and Processing.

Comment: that's too vague od a question, we can't just solve your problem you will have to be more precise on what's your problem

Comment: Looks good to me, although I think that the `gameEnd` method does not need a parameter and may just be automatically called after every move (it'll analyse the whole array anyway, no need for a specific integer). Same general principle goes for the `drawMap` method, unless you're planning on drawing more than one map at a time.

Comment: @laancelot Sounds good! Thank you! You can leave it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DaniyarAubekerov Glad it helped! I don't have the energy to make this into a in-depth answer, but I appreciate it nonetheless! Good luck!